# In a world where magic can only be used for baking, how can this be exploited to naturally lead to invention of space travel?

Tags: magic, space-travel

basically what the question says. Of course, magic must preserve the conversation of energy. Baking is defined in the normal way:

> the action of cooking food by dry heat without direct exposure to a flame, typically in an oven.

Comment: Can you describe how magic is used for baking? Something analogous to firebending? Conservation of energy is upheld; from where do the magic users draw their energy?

Comment: This depends on what your magic can achieve. If your magic simply bakes uncooked goods than its very unlikely they will achieve space travel with this, but if it has the ability to summon fire, move things by mind, etc… than it might be possible to use side effects of baking to achieve space travel. But for now please make your question more specific.

Comment: Given the non-magic techniques of baking (such as applying heat or causing chemical reactions), what exactly does your baking magic replace? Furthermore, can your baking magic be used to "cook" non-food items?

Comment: Are you asking if there are any segue compounds that create something akin to an explosive substance when combined via indirect heat? In other words, you baked a cake made out of actual food ingredients, plus extras, and caused a chemical reaction that resulted in some known propellant, then more or less elaborated that until space travel is possible? That is a huge bridge to leap, but it may not be impossible.

Comment: Magic could enhance taste by (equivalently) exchanging ingredients. It could also allow you to animate a whisk to help whip some cream for example. It could also be used to mend a collapsed soufflé when you need it most.

Comment: This will be closed for lacking detail or opinion based  but I salute your mind  it's one of a kind 

Comment: Magically bake a life size space elevator cake?

Comment: When you mean magic for baking, do you mean "magic these cookie batter blobs into cookies" or "magic to create the oven environment to cook in"?  Both potentially lead to different results and I'd hate to give an answer for one interpretation where you met the other.

Comment: Hi @Haylen, thanks for your concern, it’s a good point. I think both of those examples would be fine since they’re used for baking. Of course it would still have to preserve energy somehow, perhaps by sacrificing something dear to the baker.

Comment: @AncientGiantPottedPlant I think might just work!

Comment: "*By sacrificing something dear to the baker*": then are you talking about sentimental energy? Karma?

Comment: There are so many ways possible here, but all are deeply dependent on what the magic specifically does and doesn’t do. Clarify or be closed.

Comment: If the purpose of the magic is to replace my oven (production of heat in an enclosed space) then, obviously, it can be used to propel things (production of enough heat in an enclosed space to create an explosion, or venting, or plasma). If the magic doesn't produce heat (it "bakes" by some other method), then you need to explain your magic for this question to be answered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think of all the time/effort/energy that is used in the cooking of Food. Especially in a Medieval setting.

That's now gone.

That frees up a significant portion of time to devote to non-necessity pursuits.

Then there is the other reason for cooking food - not only does it taste yummy, but it kills bugs/parasites/bacteria - meaning it's safer to eat and there was a study from 2012 that indicated that cooked Meat in particular is good for brain growth - so to answer your question:

We needed to spend less time cooking (cause magic) and we grew bigger brains (cause cooked meat) - which causes a significant societal pivot into Science and Technology, leading to a much shortened time period to achieve space travel.

Comment: I'd argue the contrary re time spent - cooks still need to do all the pre-baking preparation of ingredients and once something is baking the cook basically can do other things except for checking on it occasionally to see if it is baked yet.  Which means that this world isn't significantly different from our world... which led to space travel.